# Как подключится к Minecraft серверу на Linux, если сам Minecraft на Windows

Tags: linux, minecraft

Сам линукс стоит через wsl
На линуксе запущен сам сервер, работает стабильно.
Каким образом можно подключится к нему?, если сам Майнкрафт стоит на Win.

Comment: А смысл ставить сервак на WSL, если Java прекрасно работает на винде?